# Присвоить переменной значение с БД sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Хотел попросить помочь мне с базами данных.
У меня есть 2 базы данных, мне нужно взять значение с одной и отнять значение с другой.
Основная загвоздка что у меня никак не получается присвоить значение переменным. Работаю c
Python sqlite3
Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Как вы пытались реализовать? Покажите ваш код. Чтобы присвоить значение из БД - достаточно присвоить данные в переменную метода курсора БД. К примеру `value = cursor.fetchone()` или же `value = cursor.fetchall()`

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy  `import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('product_minus.db')
cursor = db.cursor()

value = cursor.fetchall("""SELECT * FROM product_minus""" )
print(value)
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()` Для начала я хочу хотя б вывести данные через print

Comment: `import sqlite3
connect = sqlite3.connect('product_minus.db')
cursor = connect.cursor()

value = cursor.execute("""SELECT NAME FROM product_minus""" )
connect.commit()
print(value)
cursor.close()` Данный код выводит непонятные символы.

Comment: Ваша таблица в базе данных называется `product_minus`? Приведите в комментарии эти непонятные символы